# Is "that" omissible after "with the result"?

Tags: adjuncts, adverbials

In CGEL, while discussing the purpose adjuncts "so/in order" + that-clause (p. 727), it is stated that "that" is omissible after "so", but not after "in order".

Under result adjuncts, there is "so/with the result" + that-clause (p. 732).  There are examples with "so" without the "that", but there is just one example with "with the result", and I can't decide if it sounds correct without the "that":

*They had gambled away all their money, [**so /with the result** that they didn't even
have the fare to get home]*

Contrary to the purpose adjuncts, it is never made explicit whether or not "that" is omissible after "with the result".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are right that it's not made clear, but personally I would not drop "that" after "with the result".

Comment: In principle you can *always* drop ***that*** in all such contexts, but it's not idiomatic to do so after ***with the result*** in OP's example. Note that we wouldn't *normally* include ***that*** after ***so*** in OP's exact example, because ***so that*** there could imply the only reason they gambled in the first place was ***in order to*** end up without the fare home. Admittedly, that's a bizarre "goal", but it's what the construction would normally imply today if we include ***that***. Note that a century or two ago, this distinction didn't normally apply.

Comment: In "with the result that...", the *that*-clause is a complement of the noun *result*. I don't think it can be omitted.

Comment: A search of Google books suggests "that" is usual in such examples, although there are many other ways of using "with the result", e.g. following by an adjectival or adverbial phrase, so it is hard to search automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that I have found the answer in CGEL, chapter 11 (content calsuses), under "optional omission of that" (page 953).  It gives the following example as favouring retention

*I didn’t like his insinuation [that we had initiated the complaint]*

and comments:  *"In (the example) it is complement to a noun; omission is not impossible in this construction, but it is unlikely with a morphologically complex noun like insinuation (compare The fact [it was illegal ]didn’t seem to worry him, with the simple noun fact as head)."*

So my conclusion is that in the OP it is optional, somewhat favouring retention.